# What does "one" mean here?

Tags: meaning

> *Blockquote*
>   Delusion, addiction, obsession _ these are all the mind's desperate
>   and compulsive attempts at generating hope one neurotic tic or
>   obsessive craving at a time.

I can not understand the relationship between the phrase before "one" and the phrase after it,   so I can not get the meaning of the sentence.

So could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text is:

> "Hopelessness is the root of anxiety, mental illness, and depression. 
>   It is the source of all misery and the cause of all addition...Chronic
>   anxiety is a crisis of hope.   It is the fear of a failed future. 
>   Depression is a crisis of hope.  It is the belief in a meaningless
>   future.  Delusion, addiction, obsession - these are all the mind's
>   desperate and compulsive attempts at generating hope one neurotic tic
>   or obsessive craving at a time."

*Every Thing Is F*cked* A Book About Hope,  Mark Manson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the mind's desperate attempts at generating hope. How do they try and do this? One step at a time: the steps are neurotic tics and obsessive cravings.

Answer (score 2):

It's a part of the expression **one at a time** here, meaning *not simultaneously*, *one* ('tic' or 'craving' of hope) *after another*. https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/one%20at%20a%20time

Comment: Ok. And what is the relationship between this part of sentence and "hope". I still can not get the  meaning of last part of the sentence.

Comment: I think it's an informal simplification here for 'hopefully' or '**I** hope' (hopefully not two or more at once).

Comment: No, _Hope_ is the object of _generating_.

Comment: You are right, those tics and craving are actually  'quants' of hope, generated one by one.